# Call C function from asm file by passing function address in a register

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, linker

I have a function named `system_handler` which is defined in a `func.c`. I need to call `system_handler` from another assembly program by passing the address of the function to a register and call the register.

So far I have written this:

```
       .extern system_handler   ; Is defined in func.c
       mov system_handler, %eax
       call %eax   ; This call is making run time error in emulator 
                   ; fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x8b1cec83
```

While assembling the asm file I am getting a warning:

```
Warning: indirect call without '*'
```

compiler and assembler used: `i586-gnu-{gcc/as}`, Using AT&T format in asm file.

Comment: BTW, normally a relative call is fine, `call system_handler`.  The linker will fill in the right `rel32` when you link the `.o` files from the asm and the C.  You'd only need this if the callee also needed its own address in EAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AT&T syntax you should use `mov $system_handler, %eax` to load the address, what you did was loading the first dword of your function from memory.

To fix the warning, you should of course write `call *%eax`, which is another peculiarity of AT&T.

If you are not familiar with AT&T syntax, you can switch both `gcc` and `gas` to intel syntax.

Comment: Can i use the same **$** with the extern variables. I am getting an error when i use $ in-front of variable name.    
lgdt var   ; No error    
lgdt $var  ; Error: unsupported instruction `lgdt'

Comment: That's because `lgdt` actually wants an effective address (memory reference), not an immediate.

Comment: OK, So what should i pass for lgdt instruction ? I tried passing just the variable name and the variable name inside the brackets both of them didn't work?

Comment: Just the variable name. What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did you pass the correct address? In any case, that's a different question, you might want to create a new entry about that, providing all the details.